# How to replicate a slice in Rust?

Tags: list, rust, replicate

I have a slice that I want to replicate. For example, if `xs = [1, 2, 3]`, and I need to replicate it 4 times, I would end up with `ys = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

In Haskell, I would do something like this:

```
ys = take (4 * length xs) $ cycle xs
```

How might this be similarly done in Rust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an iterator from the array with [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html), then an endlessly repeating iterator with [`cycle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cycle), then limit it to 4 cycles with [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take).

```
fn main() {
    let xs = [5,7,13];
    let ys = xs.iter()
                .cycle()
                .take(xs.len() * 4);

    for y in ys {
        println!("{}", y);
    }
}
```